# Legend Box Size

Tags: gnuplot

The following code produce a box legend too large, how could I fix it? [image]

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color size 4.0in,3.0in background rgb "white" font "Helvetica,10" header '\usepackage{amsmath,bm} \usepackage{amssymb}'

set output 'output.tex'

set key top right box
set key width 1
set key height 1

set lmargin at screen 0.15
set rmargin at screen 0.95
set tmargin at screen 0.95
set bmargin at screen 0.15


set xrange [0:6.28]
plot sin(x) title "$\\dot{m}_{max, \\, EFT}$"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes gnuplot cannot estimate the place needed for a string accurately enough. You already use the `set key width` command, try it with a negative width.

```
set key width -3
```

Result:

[image: image with narrow key box]

From the `help set key` documentation:

> When using the TeX/LaTeX group of terminals or terminals in which formatting
> information is embedded in the string, gnuplot can only estimate the width
> of the string for key positioning.